# If my roommates use more utilities than me, am I legally allowed to pay less?

Tags: payment, utility-bills, energy

I live with three roommates. My roommates use much more electricity than I do and are constantly wasting energy, which means our utility bill is high. The bill is in the name of one of my roommates, and the rest of us pay her back each month. If i paid her less to reflect the energy that she uses and I don’t, would I be legally protected, or am I liable for that money? Our lease doesn’t say anything about how we should split utilities and we didn’t sign any sort of contract with each other.

Edit: Thanks for the responses! We live in Austin, Texas. I have looked over the lease, and all that it says is that the person who has the bill in their name is responsible for paying the utilities. I never committed to splitting the utilities exactly four ways either verbally or in writing. I know that it seems petty not to want to pay the extra for the utilities i’m not using, but they have acted very entitled to my paying for their energy usage and the roommate who has the bill in their name has been rude and unfriendly to me the entire time I have lived here. I don’t plan to stop paying her back at all, but I don’t feel like giving her money for her wasted energy that I wouldn’t be paying if she used the AC at a reasonable level. Not to mention the fact that I am always freezing cold in the apartment, so not only am I paying more for something I’m not using, I’m paying for something I actively don’t want. Thanks again!

Comment: What did you agree verbally when you took the room?

Comment: Also, if you're currently friends with your roommates, you may wish to consider whether the savings would be worth not being friends after you take them to court (or vice versa).

Comment: How do you *know* they use more than you? Do you have seperate meters or some other evidence the court would find compelling?

Comment: What Dale M said. Also note that energy usage might be non-obvious: For example, cooking an additional warm meal uses *much* more energy than forgetting to turn off a (LED) light.

Comment: maybe should there be a location tag?

Comment: @DaleM One housemate I had years ago would have a bath every night that steamed up the whole house and left no hot water for the rest of us to use -  we all had quick showers in the morning.  She also used the washing machine almost daily at 95°C.  The bills were nearly double the previous year in the same house with different people. Sometimes it's obvious when one person uses much more.  How much more is harder to judge.

Comment: What is your relationship with your roommates? Are you friends? Do you think a legal answer would be more appropriate than an amicable arrangement?

Comment: @Heinzi: Depends. 15W of LED lights for 24h is 360Wh. Running a 2kW stove for 10 minutes is 333Wh (probably enough to make a quick meal like pasta).

Comment: @Michael most LED bulbs are about 2-5 W a bulb, but indeed, keeping the flat fully illuminated with 15 W of LED 24/7 is about as much energy as you spend on cooking a pot of water with fresh noodles - a meal that in my experience takes about 10 mins to prepare.

Comment: There are two kinds of housemate. The kind who believe that labelling stuff in the refridgerator is a great idea and those who think that is smacks of selfish, non-communal living (irrespective of how well they treat the commune). It sounds to me like you landed in a group of the latter. It's entirely possible that there is no action that you can take that won't irreperably damage the relationship with you housemates. Perhaps it's time to reappraise who you live with?

Comment: I predict the energy bill will be in your name from the day you pay less onwards.

Comment: The temperature of communal spaces is always a negotiation, but electricity usage aside, remember that there's a limit to how much they can cool themselves down if they are too hot, and you can always put on a jumper if you're cold. Plus, sat there in a winter coat in the middle of summer is a great visual cue that the AC is turned up way too high.

Comment: In your own room, you should have much more control. If you have your own thermostat, just turn it up. If you have central AC, block off the AC vent in your room and use a space heater. After all, it's only fair that others pay a share of your heating if you're paying a share of their cooling. Either way, if the AC isn't cooling your room, it has to work less hard to cool the rest, other rooms will be even cooler, and your housemates may turn down the AC to compensate.

Comment: Careful about being so pissy about paying your share or how much they use vs. you.  If there was no agreement made to split it evenly, there's nothing stopping her from charging you double for the little bit of power you claim to use.  She technically has the supply and can demand a price for it.  Or maybe she says, "fine, don't use my power at all."  Then where would you be?

Answer (score 25):

If you promised to split the bill equally, that is a contract even if there was not paperwork or signature. The utility company will only come after the person on the contract with them, then that person can go after others who are not paying the agreed-to amount. Maybe there was no agreement at all and the person on the bill just *hoped* that you would split the costs.

It does also depend on what the lease for the unit says about utilities, for example "tenants shall be responsible for paying the utilities". You are one of the tenants, and with that working, you have a responsibility to pay. The courts could decide whether the bill should be split evenly, or according to individual use, and you would then have to establish that the other person uses substantially more electricity.

Comment: I imagine this plus the other answer from therac could be a great comprehensive answer;    there probably should be a location tag by the OP though

Comment: If all tenants are named on the contract, then there is also a high chance that the contract will state that the tenants are "jointly and severally liable".  That is, the utility can demand *all* the money from *any* of the tenants.

Comment: If they promised to split the bill equally, could the courts decide to not split the bill equally?  If not, your answer perhaps could use a little clarification in that regard (in the second paragraph).

Answer (score 19):

From a legal standpoint, roommates co-signing a lease are normally **jointly liable**.
Joint liability means every one of the tenants is responsible for the entire bill. If there is just one primary tenant named on the lease, then that tenant alone is responsible for the entire bill.

How you split the bill is a matter of further agreements between the four of you. It's something a court would expect roommates to work out between themselves, and solve their disputes similarly. In some jurisdictions, a documented good-faith attempt to resolve the matter via *negotiation, mediation or arbitration* is mandatory. In others it's just expected before filing a lawsuit, but it strengthens the position.

For practical purposes, even if your time is worth less than the difference in bills, the court's isn't. *De minimis non curat lex* - "the law is not concerned with small things". It's for matters that significantly impact lives or businesses, and can't be reasonably resolved in other ways.

How a group of patrons should split their bill is a textbook example of what courts usually deem below their stature. That's not because the bill is small - you could rack up $5,000 in a restaurant, but the same court will readily provide a hearing for a $50 fine.

The reason is, if a few people voluntarily decide to dine out, it carries *expected* consequences, such as the need to pay the bill. A reasonable person should either agree on the split in advance, or accept the risk of any split, up to being stuck with the whole thing. These are agreements people close enough to share such expenses are expected to resolve on their own. There's no public interest being served by the court interfering in these agreements.

There are exceptions. If one of you was *secretly* running a bitcoin farm in the house (which basically converts energy into money), it won't matter what your agreement was or if you had separate meters. This is a commercial operation, an egregious and *unexpected* abuse of a household lease, for which and the landlord and the leaseholder both have grounds to evict and sue for the costs.

Taking longer showers or using more power for cooking, TV, or even heating and AC is something you can reasonably expect of a roommate, but using that power commercially isn't.

Comment: Is it really below the court's stature?  Depending on the region, utility expenses can be a massive cost.  In some areas, utilities cost more than rent itself.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket It's not only because the amount is small, but also because roommates should be able to resolve this before resorting to legal action. Courts are meant to be the **last resort**, not the first.

Comment: I don't see evidence of the OP trying to use a court as a first resort.  Ideally, everything can be settled by people without anyone having to go to court.  But courts were, I believe, initially created with the idea of a forum in which to resolve disputes when people could not agree amongst themselves.  Granted, courts now serve the primary purpose of making judges and lawyers rich and powerful, but that's another sad story...

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket In what regions?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- In many regions in our world that is subject to weather extremes and where the government does not provide subsidized utilities.  I think this question may be USA-based, so 2 example there that come to mind are Connecticut and Texas.  In rural Connecticut, due to the long periods of freezing temperatures, people often pay more in utilities than for mortgage/rent.  In rural Texas, due to the low price of housing and the extreme heat and humidity, the same is true.

Answer (score 2):

> am I legally allowed to pay less?

Sure, why not?

Did your contract with the roommates explicitly state "XYZ% from each tenant." If it did state this then you must pay XYZ%.

The only thing stopping you from paying less is a stern defense. Apparently, you're not able to stand up for yourself and a lawyer isn't gonna do it for free so to keep peace you are paying more than your "fair share" which everyone else has no issue with.

Overall, your post seems better suited for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That. The law is a bad stand-in for failed personal relationships. Dragging your roommates to court will make it real fun to live with them.